# Ubuntu 22.04 updates broke dot net core 7.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, ubuntu-22.04

On 3 running Ubuntu servers... I did updates and now Supervisor crashes.

```
tail /var/log/PHCAdmin.err.log:
```

```
.NET location: /usr/lib/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64
```

Comment: You didn't mention if you had followed the links in the error message. Did you have any problems following the steps in them?

Comment: FYI it ".NET 7" and "ASP.NET Core 7" the .NET SDK from v5 onwards no longer uses the "Core" suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following steps (clean reinstall):

> sudo apt remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'
>
> sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
>
> sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0

Next time please provide further information on your question :)

Answer (score 0):

So I hate when people don't answer the problem but post a workaround... Sorry, I'm about to do just that. I needed to get the 3 servers up and running quickly so I just republished my app as "Self-contained" instead of "Framework Dependent" in the Publish window's "Target Framework" option.
I think the actual issue is that I have .net 7.0.5 installed after the updates but my application is targeting 7.0.0

Hope this helps someone who may be having the same issue.